# Adding page specific favicon in ASPX page that imports master header

Tags: asp.net, web, https, favicon

Trying to add a different favicon for our checkout.aspx page

Checkout.aspx uses Site.Master.cs file for it's head, this is sitewide, with the sitewide favicon.

There is no head section on checkout.aspx page itself. How do I add favicon-lock.ico so that it only shows during checkout?